# loop through server images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a very small website for a friend, he has still his old web server hosted by his internet provider, but the webspace doesn't support php oder any oder server sided language and he doesn't want to change.
Right now I'm trying to get all pictures from a folder with jquery or javascript.

I named the picture folder like the end of the url without the html extension to get the path from the url.

I found here some solutions with ajax, but is there one without server sided support?

I though of something like this pseudo code.

```
    //get the filepath magic
var i = 0;
var fileName
[];
do {
    pictureName = filepath + i;
    if (pictureName.extension == jpg) {
        fileName.push(pictureName)
        i++;
        fileExists = true
    }
    else {
        fileExists = false
    }


} while (fileExists);
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is no way to read a server side directory from a browser. You could manually make an array of the image url's. Or put them in a cloud storage service that provides back end code to read directories for you...or move to a more robust host

Comment: Maybe a cloud storage could do the trick, thanks for that advice.
Moving is no option for him, asked him twice.