# Get pictures from google drive api with javascript

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have one question, as mentioned
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224425/loop-through-server-images) I'm doing a jQuery/Javascript only homepage.

Now I'm trying to get the pictures from a google drive with the google drive API. The authentication with 0Auth worked very well.
But I'm not sure if it's the right way, because the authentication confused me a little bit.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) in Step 2 I have to use my Client ID and login with my user, does this mean the Website is now verified to use the API or does this mean everybody who wants to see the pictures has to login?

What happens if the key is not valid anymore or how often do i have to renew it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Before you can integrate Google Sign-In into your website, you must have a Google API Console project. In the project, you create a [**`client ID`**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project), which you need to call the sign-in API.

AFAIK, client ID doesn't expire, only [access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048945/oauth-v2-google-api-expiry-access-token) which expire after 60 minutes. If you have a refresh token you can use the refresh token to get a new (valid) access token.

Here's some references which might help:

- [Google Drive API using Javascript](http://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript)
- [How to use Google Drive API to download files with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860901/how-to-use-google-drive-api-to-download-files-with-javascript)